# matching multidimensional arrays by key value, preserving other values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains data in the following format:

```
$myArray = array(
    array(
            'id' = 1,
            'title' = 'the first entry',
            'data' = 'additional data'
         ),
    array(
            'id' = 2,
            'title' = 'the third entry',
            'data' = 'some more data'
         ),
    array(
            'id' = 3,
            'title' = 'the second entry',
            'data' = 'other important stuff'
         )
    );
```

(An array containing about 12 child arrays in total). This data needs to be split into two rows for displaying on my page, based on the title attribute. I know what titles I want on the first row, and which ones for the second row. So I have another array like this:

```
 $firstRow = array('the first entry', 'the second entry');
 $secondRow = array('the third entry');
```

So what I need to do is throw these 3 arrays, `$myArray, $firstRow, $secondRow` into a function which will output a new ordered array which preserves the other attributes (the `id` and `data` keys in my example) like the following:

```
$newArray = array(
    'firstRow' => array(
                      array(
                         'id' = 1,
                         'title' = 'the first entry',
                         'data' = 'additional data'
                            ),
                      array(
                         'id' = 2,
                         'title' = 'the second entry',
                         'data' = 'some more data'
                           )
                       ),
    'secondRow' => array(
                       array(
                          'id' = 3,
                          'title' = 'the third entry',
                          'data' = 'other important stuff'
                            )
                        )
                  );
```

I have some ideas, and I know there are various functions like array_intersect(), but I'm not sure which is the best to use? Hopefully someone has a quick and easy solution to this. Thanks.

Comment: just write a simple *loop*. also, your data isn't well structured, perhaps you should redesign it?

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution... but thanks. The data ($myArray) is simply structured in the way it is drawn from the database (Laravel)

Comment: Why does the back end need to know how many rows the data is going to be displayed in?
Surely that should be down to CSS? eg each entry is a div with float:left and a width set. Then they will flow into rows.

Comment: Hamish, the important thing is which *titles* appear on each row, hence I thought I could do this in the back-end. The two rows essentially form two menus on my page. You may be right though, I suppose I could just assign each element its own id based on the title and leave it to CSS

Comment: So you might have something like `$firstRow = array('the first entry', 'the third entry'); $secondRow = array('the second entry');` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking...?

Comment: Might the 12 entries be displayed out of order? ie. Which row an entry is in depends exclusively on it's title and not it's id?
If this is the case then I suggest you edit the question to reflect this: Your example of `$firstRow = array('the first entry', 'the second entry'); $secondRow = array('the third entry');` suggests that you just want the entries to be output in order but arranged in rows.

Comment: I see what you mean. In my question I state "I know what titles I want on the first row, and which ones for the second row." But I have edited my question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `foreach` to loop over the titles array, and create a new array inside the loop, depending on the title value:

```
function groupTitlesintoArrays($myArray, $firstRow, $secondRow) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($myArray as $innerArray) {
        foreach ($firstRow as $row) {
            if ($row == $innerArray['title']) {
                $result['firstRow'][] = $innerArray;
            }
        }
        foreach ($secondRow as $row) {
            if ($row == $innerArray['title']) {
                $result['secondRow'][] = $innerArray;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/94737)

Comment: @Inigo: Glad to have been of help!